# mocking util function enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

i have a function living in my utils that isn't part of a component at all

that function calls other functions, how can I mock this to test the conditional?

```
const myfunc = () =>
  funcA().funcB() ? (
    <Route path="somewhere" component={somecomponent} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
  );
```

how can I mock funcA and funcB to get them to return true and false to hit the correct part of the conditional?
also how can I test for route path props?

i have this in my test at the moment but it is not generating the correct results

```
const funcA = jest.fn();
const funcB = jest.fn();
funcA.mockReturnValue(funcB);
funcB.mockReturnValue(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Mock function A and B as follows

```js
const funcB=()=>true;

const funcA=()=>{return {funcB}};

funcA().funcB() //returns True
```

You can refer this to test a react Router.

[How to test react-router with enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531465/how-to-test-react-router-with-enzyme)